# Custom type in C# (Similar to typescript)

Tags: c#, typescript

In typescript I can define a type to be either string or string array like this

```
type MyStringType = string | string[]
```

Can I do something similar in C#?

Comment: Nope. Maybe tell us about the practical problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: This is called "discriminated union". It is (at least currently) no built-in language feature in C#, but you will find several implementation when searching.

Comment: @sweeper I'm sending table filter values back to the server. Usually it's single string for filtering by equals, contains, startsWith etc. When filtering by IN (is a member of list) I need a string array

Comment: for your explict case you could consider using the params keyword, your implementation would also have to work with a collection (sometimes with only one item) but your caller has the choice to pass in 1 or more strings very easily. Its most certainly nothing related to discrimiated unions and the typescript example you gave, but it could help with your particular issue in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# does not have a feature for union types. There are a few [proposals](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/468) but I don't think they're being planned for anytime soon.

Having that said, you can implement your custom wrapper type and have inputs converted to that type before they're used.

```
struct Union<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Left { get; } 
    public T2 Right { get; } 

    public bool IsLeft => !IsRight;
    public bool IsRight { get; } 

    public Union(T1 left) => (Left, Right, IsRight) = (left, default, false);
    public Union(T2 right) => (Left, Right, IsRight) = (default, right, true);

    public static implicit operator Union<T1, T2>(T1 left) => new Union<T1, T2>(left);
    public static implicit operator Union<T1, T2>(T2 right) => new Union<T1, T2>(right);
}
```

Thanks to the implicit conversions you can use a value of any of the variants where a union is needed. So both of these work:

```
void Foo(Union<string, string[]> val){} 

Foo("str") 
Foo(new string[] {"str1", "str2"});
```

Note that this is not a production-grade implementation. You probably want to override `Equals`, maybe throw an `InvalidOperarionException` if someone accesses `Left` when `IsLeft` is `false` and vice versa.

An actual language-supported implementation would have less overhead (probably reuse a single field of size `max(sizeof(T1), sizeof(T2)))`, but alas, this Works™ and is strongly typed.

Comment: Thanks @V0ldek this might d the trick. Not as pretty as the typescript version but that's C#'s fault.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. C# is a strongly typed language that does not
(yet) allow the declaration of a variable to be of multiple types.

There is the option to use the `dynamic` keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

> The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking. In most cases, it functions like it has type object. At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation. Therefore, you do not have to be concerned about whether the object gets its value from a COM API, from a dynamic language such as IronPython, from the HTML Document Object Model (DOM), from reflection, or from somewhere else in the program. However, if the code is not vali

Effectively it can be used as the `any` type in typescript, but it's not recommended due to possible runtime errors.

Comment: I thought about that but I want to have type checking.  I may just have to have 2 properties in my class, string StringValue and string[] StringArrayValue.

Comment: Just note that being strongly typed has nothing to do with allowing union types in your language. It's just that C# doesn't support this feature ([at least yet](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/399)).

Comment: You can use something like OneOf but it's not the same. It will add some complexity.